# postgresql.conf file been ignored

Tags: postgresql, sockets, tcp, server

I am trying to allow remote connections to postgresql on ubuntu 19, I first edited postgresql.conf, specifically the parameter listen_addresses, like this:

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
```

as this tutorial says https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/23/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection.html,
then I restarted the psql server with the following command:

```
$ service postgresql restart
```

Following, I edited pg_hba.conf file too adding these two lines at the very end:

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

restarted again the psql server. The tutorial says that this should be all but when I do the netstat -nlt command to see if it is already working, netstat shows the following information:

```
$ netstat -nlt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:42545               :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

when it shoudl be showing something like this, specifically on port 5432:

```
$ netstat -nlt
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2812          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:11211               :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

I have done some research and it might be something related with postgresql.auto.conf file overwriting the postgresql.conf file, but i could not get further since postgresql.auto.conf only shows this:

```
# Do not edit this file manually!
# It will be overwritten by the ALTER SYSTEM
```

I would appreciate some help about this issue, thanks.

Comment: Checkout if you are editing the right conf file. SQL: `SHOW config_file;`

Comment: I finally found the solution, I made the `ALTER SYSTEM SET LISTEN_ADDRESSES = '*';`  but thank you for your help!